# Math - three items in vertical row (super, normal, and subscript)

Tags: math-mode, pdftex, mathtools

I'm looking to create something similiar to the following image:

[image: equation]

But I'm having trouble on how to stack the N, \cap, and i=1 item vertically as shown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, the limits in displaystyle are set under the operator (equivalent to `\limits`) and the limits in textstyle and scriptstyle are set on the side of the operator (equivalent to `\nolimits`). You can change that by explicitly adding `\limits` and `\nolimits`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
  \sum\nolimits_{\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^N A_i = B}
\]
\end{document}
```

which gives

[image]